# Disable loading script with timestamp

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I want to disable the timestamp when loading the script, as it always includes a timestamp in the query string after the file URL. Please look at the image you will know.

[image]

I have also set up Ajax with the option `cache: true`. See the code here:
``js
$.ajax({
  url: url
  data: {},
  type: 'post',
  cache: true,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data, status) {
    //something here
  }
});

````
and also I have set meta tag to the header of the HTML.
```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="Public">
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
<meta name="keywords" content="something">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
````

I am using jQuery v1.7.2

Comment: Those were for `GET` but above you have `POST`

Comment: so that means I need to do all ajax with POST ?

Comment: but look at the first line, I just load jQuery. but why it has timestamp?

Comment: jquery does not modify links. Your `url` variable is flawed, make sure you don't attach that booster to it by your own script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why jQuery is trying to load itself, but this seems to be related to `$.getScript()` calls.

You could consider adding the following snippet as high up as possible:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true
});
```

Putting the `cache: true` in your `$.ajax()` doesn't affect `$.getScript()` in any way and that's what you're seeing in that screenshot.

Comment: where should I put this?

     $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: true 
     });

because I already put cache:true in ajax function.

Comment: @Sml004 you should put it right after the `<script src=".../jquery-1.7.2.js"` in your HTML, inside a separate `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about codeIgniter directly, but it should be the same as in CakePHP. You should have a file name something like config or whatever similar which contains a debug level. When its set to debug mod, it probably auto timestamps the scripts and handle the stacks for errors differently

Comment: yes, I set it to level 4 which will log all errors. but when I disable it (set to 0), I still get timestamp.

Comment: there should be another variable! Im currently looking at codeIgniter code  to try to find it. In cake there's a variable called asset.timestamp that I can put to true or false (and there are way to link it with the debug level also). There should be somehting similar in code igniter!

Comment: what codeIgniter function do you use to load scripts? do you just load them with an html string or do you load them with a function?

Comment: I just load script with html. <script..></script>

Comment: well, then I'm sorry, I really don't know!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajaxPrefilter('script', function(options) {
    options.cache = true;
});

// or 

+ function($) {
    $.cachedScript = function(url, options) {
        // Allow user to set any option except for dataType, cache, and url
        options = $.extend(options || {}, {
            dataType: "script",
            cache: true,
            url: url
        });

        // Use $.ajax() since it is more flexible than $.getScript
        // Return the jqXHR object so we can chain callbacks
        return $.ajax(options);
    };
}(jQuery);

// now, you can use $.cachedScript()
```

You can go to view the document [$.getScript()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)